# AttributeError: module 'Tkinter' has no attribute '__file__'

Tags: python, tkinter

I use python 3.6, and new to Tkinter.

When I run in Pycharm:

```
import Tkinter
print (Tkinter.__file__)
```

I have the following:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/Shultais/Practic/Tkinter/tkinter.py", line 6, in 
    print (Tkinter.**file**)
AttributeError: module 'Tkinter' has no attribute '**file**'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: are you aware that you're importing your module named `Tkinter`, and not the standard python package of the same name?

Comment: I try to import standard python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For python 3.6, the package is named `tkinter`, not `Tkinter`.